# emulator file not present in compiled AOSP out directory

Tags: android, emulation, android-source, rom

I have compiled AOSP, for target arm and emulator. As per expected, emulator file should be present in out directory of compiled AOSP.But it is not present in directory. 
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The `emulator` file is never in `out/`. After running `lunch`, the emulator binary from `prebuilts/android-emulator/<host-and-arch>/` will be added to your path. The prebuilt emulator binary will look for .img files in `$ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT` which is also defined after running the `lunch` bash function. Note that `lunch` is added as a bash function after running `source build/envsetup.sh`.

As per the build instructions on the AOSP page, make sure you source the build/envsetup.sh and run lunch to define a target.